# Can one copy and paste from a dialogue box in lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

Can one copy and paste from an error box in lubuntu?

I've learnezd about the clipboard and the different copy paste functions for text in windows but from the guvcview error box, I can't highlight text with either/any mouse button combinations.

Comment: @mark, hopefully my question edit helps.

Comment: It did, I changed my vote.

Comment: I managed to copy system information, using the copy to clipboard button in the system window, using paste from the pulldown menu, so playing with my mouse buttons should resolve that one, thank you mark.  However, highlighting text from the guvcview error box I still can't do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when you select text in Linux, it is automatically sent to clipboard, so just select the text in the dialog box, then use middle click to paste (just pressing the button will paste, no context menu), if you don't have a middle mouse button then simultaneously pressing left and right click would paste.

Comment: thank you dessert and Alex.  However, is there anyway to highlight text in an error box?

Comment: Unless when you hover and drag across the text it select, I'm afraid it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

In [hardinfo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hardinfo), in Lubuntu called *System Profiler and Benchmark* you can copy information by clicking the **Copy to Clickboard** button in the toolbar or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This will copy the whole page rather than the highlighted line though.